# Could one use Laravel just for the login/authentication system?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, frameworks

Is it possible to use Laravel alongside another php application not built with a framework just for the login/authentication system?

Looking at other posts, I realize that's not the point of php frameworks, but my thought was for maximum security, using a framework would be best.

Comment: I can see it being more complicated to use _just_ the authentication from a framework with your own code than to do either or. But I could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely feasible, yes. Especially if said application was properly classed and namespaced.

If it's not classed / namespaced, that rules out simply including it in Laravel. That'd likely be *way* more headache than it's worth.

In terms of security, there are a lot of routes you can go. In fact, there are authentication websites that take user information completely off of your hands. It may be worth looking into them.

The easiest solution would be to either find a **class or library** that is dedicated to authentication, and simply include it in your application (example here: http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/ or simply search for `PHP Authentication Library`). They're framework agnostic, and will be very simple to integrate into your project.

The bottom line is, you probably want something that's **agnostic** to frameworks / coding architectures. That'll be the easiest to integrate into a custom project.